# Expectation of exponential of 3 correlated Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Consider,
[image]
are correlated Brownian motions with a given [image]

I want to calculate the,
[image] , [image]

I can't think of a way to solve this although I have solved an expectation question with only a single exponential Brownian Motion

Comment: could you show how you solved it for just one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Besides @StackG's splendid answer, I would like to offer an answer that is based on the notion that the multivariate Brownian motion is of course [multivariate normally distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution), and on its [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function).

We know that

$$
\mathbb{E}\left(W_{i,t}W_{j,t}\right)=\rho_{i,j}t
$$

i.e. an $N$-dimensional vector $X$ of correlated Brownian motions has time $t$-distribution (assuming $t_0=0$:

$$
X_t\sim \mathbb{N}\left(\mathbf{\mu},\mathbf{\Sigma}\right)=\mathbb{N}\left( \begin{bmatrix}0\\ \ldots \\\ldots \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, t\times\begin{bmatrix}1 & \rho_{1,2} & \ldots & \rho_{1,N}\\
\rho_{1,2} & 1 & \ldots & \rho_{2,N}\\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
\rho_{1,N}&\rho_{2,N}&\ldots & 1
\end{bmatrix}\right)
$$

The MGF of the multivariate normal distribution is

$$
M_X(\mathbf{t})\equiv\mathbb{E}\left( e^{\mathbf{t}^T\mathbf{X}}\right)=e^{\mathbf{t}^T\mathbf{\mu}+\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{t}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{t}}
$$

In your case, $\mathbf{\mu}=0$ and $\mathbf{t}^T=\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_1&\sigma_2&\sigma_3\end{pmatrix}$. Hence,

$$
\begin{align}
M_X(\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_1&\sigma_2&\sigma_3\end{pmatrix})&=e^{\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_1&\sigma_2&\sigma_3\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{\Sigma}\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_1 \\ \sigma_2 \\ \sigma_3\end{pmatrix}}\\
&=e^{\frac{1}{2}t\left(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2+\sigma_3^2+2\sigma_1\sigma_2\rho_{1,2}+2\sigma_1\sigma_3\rho_{1,3}+2\sigma_2\sigma_3\rho_{2,3}\right)}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks for this - far more rigourous than mine.

Answer (score 11):

You need to rotate them so we can find some orthogonal axes.

A simple way to think about this is by remembering that we can decompose the second of two brownian motions into a sum of the first brownian and an independent component, using the expression
\begin{align}
W_{t,2} = \rho_{12} W_{t,1} + \sqrt{1-\rho_{12}^2} \tilde{W}_{t,2}
\end{align}
where $\tilde{W}_{t,2}$ is now independent of $W_{t,1}$

If we apply this expression twice, we get
\begin{align}
W_{t,2} &= \rho_{12} W_{t,1} + \sqrt{1-\rho_{12}^2} \tilde{W}_{t,2} \\
W_{t,3} &= \rho_{13} W_{t,1} + \sqrt{1-\rho_{13}^2} \tilde{W}_{t,3}
\end{align}

We still don't know the correlation of $\tilde{W}_{t,2}$ and $\tilde{W}_{t,3}$ but this is determined by the correlation $\rho_{23}$ by repeated application of the expression above, as follows
\begin{align}
\rho_{23} &= \rho_{12}\rho_{13} + \sqrt{(1-\rho_{12}^2)(1-\rho_{13}^2)} \rho(\tilde{W}_{t,2}, \tilde{W}_{t,3}) \\
\rho(\tilde{W}_{t,2}, \tilde{W}_{t,3}) &= {\frac {\rho_{23} - \rho_{12}\rho_{13}} {\sqrt{(1-\rho_{12}^2)(1-\rho_{13}^2)}}} = \tilde{\rho}
\end{align}
so we can re-express $\tilde{W}_{t,3}$ as
\begin{align}
\tilde{W}_{t,3} &= \tilde{\rho} \tilde{W}_{t,2} + \sqrt{1-\tilde{\rho}^2} \tilde{\tilde{W}}_{t,3}
\end{align}

Now we can express your expectation as the sum of three independent terms, which you can calculate individually and take the product:
\begin{align}
& {\mathbb E}[e^{\sigma_1 W_{t,1} + \sigma_2 W_{t,2} + \sigma_3 W_{t,3}}] \\
&= {\mathbb E}[e^{(\sigma_1 + \sigma_2 \rho_{12} + \sigma_3 \rho_{13}) W_{t,1} + (\sqrt{1-\rho_{12}^2} + \tilde{\rho})\tilde{W}_{t,2} + \sqrt{1-\tilde{\rho}} \tilde{\tilde{W_{t,3}}}}] \\
&= {\mathbb E}[e^{(\sigma_1 + \sigma_2 \rho_{12} + \sigma_3 \rho_{13}) W_{t,1}}] {\mathbb E}[e^{(\sigma_2\sqrt{1-\rho_{12}^2} + \sigma_3\tilde{\rho})\tilde{W}_{t,2}}]{\mathbb E}[e^{\sigma_3\sqrt{1-\tilde{\rho}} \tilde{\tilde{W_{t,3}}}}]
\end{align}
So it's just the product of three of your single-Weiner process expectations with slightly funky multipliers

Answer (score 2):

One can also apply Ito's lemma (for correlated Brownian motion) for the function
$$ f(I_1, I_2, I_3) = e^{I_1+I_2+I_3}.$$
The resulting SDE for $f$ will be of the form (with explicit t as an argument now)
$$f(t) = f(0) + \frac{1}{2}k\int_0^t f(s) ds + \int_0^t \ldots dW_1 + \ldots$$
in which $k = \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 +\sigma_3^2 + 2 \rho_{12}\sigma_1\sigma_2 + 2 \rho_{13}\sigma_1\sigma_3 + 2 \rho_{23}\sigma_2\sigma_3$ and the stochastic integrals haven't been explicitly stated, because their expectation will be zero.

By taking the expectation of $f$ and defining $m(t) := \mathrm{E}[f(t)]$, we will get (with Fubini's theorem)
$$m(t) = m(0) + \frac{1}{2}k\int_0^t m(s) ds.$$
Differentiating with respect to t and solving the resulting ODE leads then to the result.